# Python dict as local, not reference

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm trying to get my little script working but I don't know what the problem is.

One of the methods will modify my test `dict` `var` even if I don't return it. I mean, I want to work with that locally and NOT to return the value. This is not my actual code but you can be sure that it is representative.

```
>>> class check:
...   def pathgen(self,test):
...     test['a']=0
...     print test
...   def assign(self):
...     test={'a':1}
...     self.pathgen(test)
...     print test #WILL PRINT 0
... 
>>> a=check()
>>> a.assign()
{'a': 0}
{'a': 0}
```

Comment: That is correct. The dictionary object passed is **mutated** - this is because Python is [Call By (Object) Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). Add another key, `'hello': 'world!'` and *don't* change that in `pathgen`. What are the results? If you want to modify a dictionary inside `pathgen`, create a *new* dictionary object that is a *copy* of the original and use that.

Comment: @pst I didn't hear "Call by sharing" term previously, interesting.

Comment: Will print the same twice. Then i can't use dict for my project!

Comment: Another term for this is *call by assignment*.

Comment: @wRAR I prefer to use it to avoid ambiguity with "Pass by Reference" / "Pass by Value [of the Reference]", which can be taken to mean an entirely different things (or the same thing) across different languages. It's just one less confusing thing to deal with and it's also suitable to be used to describe the same behavior in languages like JavaScript which do not use "reference" to discuss calling conventions or implementation specifications. It's one thing to talk about how a language works, and another to talk about how it's actually implemented.

Comment: Thanks. i really didn't know about Call By Sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want changes to an object to be local to the function that changes it you need to copy the object.  You can either copy the dictionary upon calling:

```
self.pathgen(dict(test))
```

or copy within the callee.

```
def pathgen(self, test):
    test = dict(test)
    ...
```

Comment: Note that this will generate a shallow copy. Objects contained in the dictionary may still be modified. Also have a look at the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).